# Cannot select Subreport in Visual Studio 2010 reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reportviewer, subreport

I had created a Master report and subreport (rdlc).

In the master report, i insert a subreport and right click to select "subreport property".

but there is no report can select in the drop down list of "Use this report as a subreport"

[image]

So I manually input the subreport name in the textbox.

assign parameter in master report and add parameter in subreport.

[image]

[image]

[image]

but there is error that cannot retrieve data for subreport

[image]

How can I fix the error ?
and how can i select the report in the drop down list of subreport property ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that master and subreport are in the same folder.